# variable if() statements from a setting?

Tags: php, variables, if-statement

So let's say I have an option page that will set `$threshold` as `'1'`, `'2'`, `'3'`, `'4'`, or `'5'`

I've got a form that submits/redirects differently based on that threshold (right now the threshold is set to `three` only, not changeable, so `one`, `two`, and `three` go to **PAGE ONE** and do **FUNCTION ONE**, while `four` and `five` got to **PAGE TWO** and do **FUNCTION TWO**.

I want people to be able to set their own threshold.

**currently I have:**

```
if($foo == 'five' || $foo == 'four' || $foo == 'three'){
    //DO ALL THIS CRAZY STUFF
} else {
    //DO ALL THIS OTHER STUFF
}
```

**what I WANT is basically a threshold wrapped around that:**

```
if($threshold == '5'){
    if($foo == 'five'){
        //DO ALL THIS CRAZY STUFF
    } else {
        //DO ALL THIS OTHER STUFF
    }
} else if ($threshold =='4'){
    if($foo =='five' || $foo == 'four')
```

if($foo == 'five'){
            //DO ALL THIS CRAZY STUFF
        } else {
            //DO ALL THIS OTHER STUFF
        }
    }

etc. for 3, 2, and 1 as well.

Is there an easy way to do that? Like should I set the if/or statements as variables? like:

```
if($threshold == '5'){ $var = "$foo =='five'" }
else if($threshold == '4'){ $var = "$foo =='five' || $foo == 'four'" }
```

then do

```
if($var){
    //DO ALL THIS CRAZY STUFF
} else {
    //DO ALL THIS OTHER STUFF
}
```

??

I'm not quite sure the 'best approach' to this :/

Comment: Are the "do all this crazy stuff" and "do all this other stuff" blocks the same for each threshold value?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't really understand what you want nor what your problem is ...

Comment: it's hard to understand what you are trying to do... but maybe the answer involves using ´in_array()´, so insted of doing ´$foo == 'five' || $foo == 'four' || $foo == 'three'´ you could do ´in_array($foo,$acepted_values)´ where ´$acepted_values´ is an arrays in your settings

Comment: Store the user specified threshold in a session. `if ($whatever <= $_SESSION['threshold']) {} else {}`

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but yes "Do all this other stuff" and "do all this crazy stuff" are large blocks of PHP. But each IS THE SAME in every instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really sure if, for different `$threshold` numbers and `$foo` combinations, you have different functions for each of them, or if you just want to know if `$foo` is located within the specified `$threshold`. I guess the latter is your goal:

```
// the map
$thresholds = array(
 5 => array('five'),
 4 => array('five','four'),
 // etc
);

// dummy values
$threshold = 5;
$foo = "four";

// check values
if(array_key_exists($threshold,$thresholds)) {
  if(in_array($foo, $thresholds[$threshold]))  {
    //DO ALL THIS CRAZY STUFF
  }
  else {
    //DO ALL THIS OTHER STUFF
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to make complex decisions, based on multiple vars, a good strategie is to build a map.

A map is a multi dimension array and has a function name or a closure as a value. What you do is lookup what function to call based on the keys of the array.